# If, then, else regex - How to write the Condition

Tags: php, regex

Trying to capture name= and value= US or NONE (if selected="selected" not included). Given the following (part of a larger $page):

```
$page = '
<select name="country" ><option value="NONE">Select One</option>    
<option value="AE">UNITED ARAB EMIRATES</option>
<option value="GB">UNITED KINGDOM</option>
<option value="US" selected="selected">UNITED STATES</option>
<option value="UY">URUGUAY</option>
<option value="UZ">UZBEKISTAN</option>
<option value="ZW">ZIMBABWE</option></select>';
```

Edit 1 This pattern won't pick up NONE if none of the options are selected.

```
$pattern = '/select name="([a-zA-Z]*)"\s?>[\w\W]*value="([A-Z]{2,4})"(selected="selected">)?/'
```

So, I'm looking for a pattern that will.

Comment: Use an HTML parser, not a regular expression.

Comment: There is no `name` attribute...

Comment: Thanks nickb, I have read plenty about that. The question is about regex. More particularly, about the persistent non-true result. Any advice?

Comment: @DavidC, Yeah, you are advised to use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the if, then, else regex in php is:

```
(if 'selected=' found) then find pattern     | else find this pattern
  (if condition)        then regex           |   else regex
(?(?=.*selected=)value="([A-Z]+)"\s+selected=|value="(NONE)">)
```

The `.*` is necessary for the condition to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be one regex ?

I would recommend splitting it up this way:

- match the  element
- tryMatch  with the "selected" attribute
- proceed according to results - I'm not sure what the logic is as don't quite undestand from your description when you want which value. But either way it should be easy to get either value or name attributes.

The benefit of this approach is that you are working on a part of the html code and it's far less error prone.

**EDIT:**

BTW: how do you know it never evaluates to true ? It seems to work as intended (i.e. matching 'select' or 'select name="country") here
 http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm

(you need to escape the quotes `(?(?=selected=\"selected\")select|select name=\"([a-zA-Z]*)\")` to use it there)

**EDIT2**

I still won't be able to help you with if then else, but based on your explanation I can suggest this:

```
<select name="([^"]*)".*?(?!</select>)<option value="[^"]*" selected="selected"|<select name="([^"]*)"\s*>\s*<option value="([^"]*)">
```

- so, tryMatch selected, if it fails match just the first option

Comment: I was intending to learn about the if conditional. Since posting the question, I've begun proceeding with your suggestion. To me, it is fine to have one long regex with | between choices.

Comment: Thanks Joanna. See my edit 1. The desire is for a pattern that will catch name="(country)" and either value="(US)" or value="(NONE)", depending on what pre-selected. Parenthesis for desired capture characters.

Comment: Regarding the if syntax, I must be using it wrong. Using the escaped string you provided, the result is always the 'else' side. I was in the process of creating the 'if', because I couldn't get the other (edit 1) to work either. Either way is fine. Just looking for 'name' and 'value'.